# Detect and extract changing numbers in list of strings

Tags: python, algorithm, language-agnostic

Let's say I have a list of of audio file names (it could be any list of strings with continuing numbers in it) that have different naming schemes but all of them contain the track number in their file name.

I want to extract the changing numbers.

**Example 1**

```
Fooband 41 - Live - 1. Foo Title
...
Fooband 41 - Live - 11. Another Foo Title
```

**Desired result**

A list of numbers: `1,2,3,...,11`

**Example 2**

```
02. Barband - Foo Title with a 4 in it
05. Barband - Another Foo Title
03. Barband - Bar Title
...
17. Barband - Yet another Foo Title
```

**Desired result**

A list of numbers: `2,5,3,...,17`

Since the position of the index number is not fixed, I (think) I cannot use regular expressions there.

**What I have**

1. Find a common prefix and suffix of the strings and chop that off
2. See if there's a number on the left / right side of the string
3. Use that number for getting the indices

But there's a problem: If I find a common prefix for **Example 1**, the common prefix would be
`Fooband 41 - Live - 1`, so `1` would be lost (likewise for a naming scheme like `Song X - 10, Song X - 11, ...)`.

### Question

**What's a good way to detect and extract the changing number (on a similar position) in a list of strings?**

I'm using Python (not that it matters for this problem)

A bonus would be if I could detect Roman numbers as well, but I suspect that'd be much more difficult.

Comment: I think you should have a straight structure of naming your audio file names, that you get a solution for all situations.

Comment: Yes, but I just wanted to illustrate the problem with audio files for easier understanding (I'm actually quite pedantic when it comes to naming audio files ;-). A solution should work for any list of strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
f = open('data.txt')
data = []

pattern = "\d+|[IVX]+"
regex = re.compile(pattern)

for line in f:
    matches = re.findall(regex, line)
    data.append(matches)

f.close()

print data
transposed_data = zip(*data)
print transposed_data

for atuple in transposed_data:
    val = atuple[0]

    if all([num==val for num in atuple]): 
        next
    else:
        print atuple
        break
```

data.txt:

```
Fooband 41 - Live - 1. Foo Title
Fooband 41 - Live - 2. Foo Title
Fooband 41 - Live - 3. Foo Title
Fooband 41 - Live - 11. Another Foo Title
```

--output:--

```
[['41', '1'], ['41', '2'], ['41', '3'], ['41', '11']]
[('41', '41', '41', '41'), ('1', '2', '3', '11')]
('1', '2', '3', '11')
```

data.txt:

```
01. Barband - Foo Title with a 4 in it
05. Barband - Another Foo Title
03. Barband - Bar Title
17. Barband - Yet another Foo Title
```

--output:--

```
[['01', '4'], ['05'], ['03'], ['17']]
[('01', '05', '03', '17')]
('01', '05', '03', '17')
```

data.txt:

```
01 Barband - Foo Title with a (I) in it
01 Barband - Another Foo (II) Title
01. Barband - Bar Title (IV)
01. Barband - Yet another (XII) Foo Title
```

--output:--

```
[['01', 'I'], ['01', 'II'], ['01', 'IV'], ['01', 'XII']]
[('01', '01', '01', '01'), ('I', 'II', 'IV', 'XII')]
('I', 'II', 'IV', 'XII')
```

Comment: Took me a second or two to figure it out, but this is quite nice!

Answer (score 0):

If they are formatted similarly, you could use python's [re module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html). A short code that would extract those numbers from a list of strings would look like this:

```
import re
regex = re.compile(".*([0-9]+).*")

number = regex.match("Fooband 41 - Live - 1. Foo Title").group(1)
```